# Why am I getting this LINQ error inside my api controller?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core app primarily using Razor Pages updated from 2.2 to 3.0 trying to implement jQuery Autocomplete on a textbox

Inside my api controller there is a search method which searches for a user's Full Name given letters entered in a textbox. When testing with postman, I get this exception:

> The LINQ expression 'Where<>(\r\n    source: DbSet<>, \r\n
>   predicate: (i) => i.FullName.ToUpper().Contains((Unhandled parameter:
>   __ToUpper_0)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
>   by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
>   ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Note I use a different name than `<user>`

Is the LINQ query wrong in some way or did I miss something when upgrading from .NET Core SDK 2.2 to 3.0?

API Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using <project name>.Data;
using <project name>.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace <project name>.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SearchUserController : ControllerBase
    {
        // instance variables

        private readonly UserManager<<user>> _userManager;
        public SearchUserController(UserManager<<user>> userManager)
        {

            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [HttpGet("Search")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
        {
            try
            {
                string term = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
                //var userFound = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.FullName.Contains(term));

                var UserList = await _userManager.Users
                    .Where(u => u.FullName.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()))
                    .OrderBy(u => u.FullName)
                    .ToListAsync();
                return Ok(UserList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods from `Startup.cs`

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<InTandemUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            })
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers();
            // deprecated code
            /*services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Events/Index", "");
            });*/
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Events/Index", "");
            });
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, RegisterAuthorizationHandler>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ManagerAuthorizationHandler>();

            services.AddScoped<UserService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: After removing `.ToUpper` I had to work on it giving me an error for using `.Contains` and wrote this code referring to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
        {
            try
            {
                string term = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
                var users = await (from u in _userManager.Users
                                      select u).ToListAsync();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
                {
                    users = users.Where(u => u.FullName.Contains(term)).ToList();
                }
                return Ok(users);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

Any way to make `users = users.Where(u => u.FullName.Contains(term)).ToList();` async?

Comment: Data comparison in SQL queries is non-case sensitive, you don't require to use ToUpper(). Entity framework is not able to convert ToUpper to appropriate SQL syntax that's why you are getting this  error.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya That depends on the collation of the fields searched. Generally the default collation is case insensitive, but not always.

Comment: I agree @Graham.

Comment: As noted by others, `string.ToUpper` isn't supported by SQL Server. When you write an EF query, the associated *Expression* eventually needs to get translated to a SQL Server query. If you use something that isn't translatable, you will fire that error. The out-of-box US English version of SQL uses a collation that ignores case. You can also use functions like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/sqlclient-for-ef-functions

Comment: Alright, I made an edit where I changed some code, any way to make this code more async or no?